# Redirect not working publishing application

Tags: angular

I'm having some trouble after publishing my angular project to a VPS.

When I run my project locally on my machine the routing and directly linking to specific pages works good. After building the project using:

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer
```

Everything seems to be working fine, except for the routing. When I press a button that changes the routing the page works fine and the new routing module is loaded. However when I manually change the address in the browser URL box, I receive the following error:

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has
>   occurred.

Sometimes it returns a 404.

Does anyone know what could cause this issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: [Routed apps must fallback to index.html](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml)

Comment: [HashLocationStrategy](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/location-strategies-angular/)

Comment: Go thorough the link provided it includes explanation as well as the solution so Either you configure your server or use `hashLocation` strategy.

Comment: Thanks @Vikas that seemed to work. When I tried the server redirect method the first time it didn't seem to work. This time it solved it!